# SSRS grey out parameters

Tags: reporting-services

We have a requirement in ssrs.
We are having 2 parameters.
Of these 2 parameters.one value will get data based on parent parameter.

Can we do grey out child parameter based on parent parameter value selected

Comment: You can't control a parameters visibility. I think your best bet is to have the Child parameter ALLOW NULLS. Then make a query for the parameter that's based on the parent parameter that only has NULL values when your desired parent parameter is selected. The user will only have a blank value in the child parameter text box - it just won't be grey (or is it gray).

Comment: Is there any chance that text box parameter can be grey out or user cannot have any values in text box

Comment: No, you cannot grey it out.. if the child parameters come from a dataset based on parent parameter, why not have a set of allowed values from the child parameter dataset . This way, the end user will not be able to put in anything that is not meant to be in there!